# C++ syntactic sugar for two phase look-up

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I am trying to provide an API where an user can statically inherit from a base class and use its methods.

The issue is that the class is `template`d with `typename T` and the methods are `template`d with `typename U`, such that the use of the methods is really cumbersome (I think, for an API).

As far as I understood this is intended since the compiler cannot resolve (the dependent?) methods.

```
template<typename T>
struct base {
    template<typename U>
    void foo(){}
};

template<typename B>
struct child : B
{
    void barr(){
        B::template foo<float>();
        this->template foo<float>();

        /* 
        B::foo<float>(); - ERROR: expected primary-expression before ‘float’
        this->foo<float>(); - ERROR: expected primary-expression before ‘float’
        foo<float>(); - ERROR:  error: ‘foo’ was not declared in this scope 
        */
    }
};

int main(){

    child<base<bool>> c;
    c.barr();

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way that I could get rid of `template` keyword in the call to `foo`?
Maybe some syntactic sugar I don't know of?

Comment: would be great if it works for c++17

Comment: There is no "syntactic sugar" for this, in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is indeed caused by the compiler's need to resolve `foo` before deciding that `foo<` isn't calling `operator<` on the expression `foo`. Adding `template` means that the compiler knows `foo<`  is the start of a template argument list.

As the author of `base`, there's nothing you can do about that. That's the whole point of the two-phase compilation. The compiler trips over the `foo<` in the first pass, where all it knows is that `child<B>` inherits from some unknown `B`.

Comment: Would it be possible, at least, for the owner of `child` to declare that `foo<float>` is a template of `B` in only one place, such that he does not need to re-write `B::template ` for every call to `foo`? I tried adding `using B::template foo<float>` but it throws an compiler error. The best I could do was `using B::template foo`  but I still needed to call foo like `B::template foo<float>();`.

Comment: @mehe: Probably the easiest solution is to implement a true wrapper `template <typename U> void foo( ) { this->template foo<float>(); }`.  Gets a bit more verbose if you need perfect forwarding of random argument lists.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `foo` member function template to `child` that just calls the one in `B`. That is,

```
template<typename T>
struct base {
    template<typename U>
    void foo() {}
};

template<typename B>
struct child : B
{
    void barr() {
        foo<float>();
    }

    template<typename T>
    void foo() {
        typename B::template foo<T>();
    }
};
```

Comment: The thing is that I want `class child` to be implemented by an user. And I want this user to write as less code as possible, which is why this whole `B::template ` (nonsense) should be gone.